# Parent Controller's scope vs Shared Service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a screen with multiple sub screens each having their own controller.
If they are to share data between them, Between having a parent controller with the top scope or Having a shared service, Which is more idiomatic to AngularJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shared service is a better option for simple data sharing between controllers.
using controller's inheritance ties your logic with the view, which makes your code less flexible and error prone:

- you can't use one controller on the page without the other (ties the
  parent to children).
- you have to ensure that controllers are declared in the correct order.
- mid-parent controllers may shadow top parent variables.

you may also consider using an event model(with `$rootscope`), if you have to notify many controllers.